# How do you get Facebook share button to work in html?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get Facebook share button to work. I copied the code directly from the developer's page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/. The thing is it does not show up on the html form.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="zh-tw">
<title>Newsletter</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how to get the button to work. I am not sure if I have html5.

Comment: You need to include the JavaScript SDK at the beginning of your file. Check out the link you shared.

Comment: It says to post after the <body> tag. I tried the code with app ID on the JavaScript SDK page, the button still does not show up.

Comment: BTW, the "Share" button is deprecated now and Facebook advocates the use of the like button now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script will work if the server runs it. For instance, if I place above script I posted in /var/www in Linux and open it from Firefox web browser then it would work. If I just open the file from /home/ then it would not work. I can no longer find the link that answered my question. I will be sure to include a link next time I find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

to

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Or use `https` if that is what you are using.

Comment: I found the answer in another stackoverflow post, I had to upload the file to the server to get it to work, thank you for the comment still.

Comment: Can you please post the correct answer or a link to the stackoverflow post that solved your problem?